# Can I make a #define macro throw a conditional warning?

Tags: c-preprocessor, gcc-warning, preprocessor-directive

I have two preprocessor macros like this:

```
#define MyFullMacro(arg1, arg2) ; doSomething(prefix##arg1, arg2);
#define MyMacro(arg2) ; doSomething(prefixDefault, arg2);
```

When `MyFullMacro` is called and explicitly given `Default` for `arg1`, I want to throw a compile warning saying something like "You're using the default argument; please use `MyMacro()` instead." **Is this possible?**

---

This will be used in Objective-C compiled with LLVM. Preferable answers should work in any language compiled with GCC/Clang/LLVM.